# how to put a span under another one, in order to write simple math?

Tags: html, css

I want to write some simple math in html.

Mathjax is too heavy and seems like an overkill. Mathml does not seem to be compatible with chrome and ie.

I would just like to write `max_x f(x)` with the x under the `max`.

`<sub>` is not enough. Because, it still put `x` in front of `max`, not completely under it.

My best try so far is:

```
<span>max
    <span style="position: relative;left:-1em;vertical-align: -.8em;font-size:smaller">x</span>
</span>
f(x)
```

It "kind of" works, but, it introduces a space between `max` and `f(x)` which has the same width than `x`.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are expecting the output but do you need something like this? So in here, am just using a `position: relative;` for the parent element, and than am setting `f(x)` to `position: absolute;` but just make sure you have a `position: relative;` container there...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8sQD/)

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
}
```

You can make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14088813/1542290) level of complicated formulas

Comment: You can also bring the `f(x)` closer by tweaking the `right` value http://jsfiddle.net/d8sQD/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can check this also, I am not sure, if you want something like this:

`<p style="position:relative;">maxf(x)<br/><span style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:20px;">x</span></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach to using positioning. For this markup

```
<span class="frac">max
    <span>x</span>
</span>
f(x)
```

do this:

```
.frac { display:inline-table; text-align:center; }
.frac span { display:table-row; }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/97r9m/